# I want duplicate the Organization record in vtiger Quotes Module

Tags: module, quotes, vtiger

I want duplicate the Organization record in Quotes Module

Because I've Recording clients and partners in Organization Module .
And I want to show customers and partners in Quotes Module.
I want to repeat this record again

Answer (score 0):

You can export your Organization record which you want to be in the Quotes Module and then import it back into Quotes Module.